# Uptime information updated in the command prompt

Tags: bash, zsh, prompt, uptime

I want to put the `uptime` command information into the command prompt and have it updated every 750ms (regardless of whether I'm typing at the prompt or not).

I usually use `bash` but I've used `zsh` too, which brings me here. I have a feeling that `bash` will not be sufficient and appreciate any help.

---

My apologies for missing this piece.

The intended prompt would look:

```
10:07:09 up 54 min,  7 users,  load average: 0.23, 0.38, 0.44
~/Videos ($)
```

I like the idea of the privilege level identifier in parentheses after the working directory. Then having the uptime information updating regularly, but it doesn't have to be 750ms.

Again, big sorry for not giving more info to start.

Thank you, everyone, in advance

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```
TRAPALRM() { psvar[1]=$(uptime); zle reset-prompt; }
RPS1='%1v'
TMOUT=1
```

You'd have the output of `uptime` in the right prompt updated every second. For 750ms, you can't use `$TMOUT` which  takes integers only.

You could do instead:

```
zmodload zsh/zselect
RPS1='%1v'
TRAPALRM() {
  (zselect -t 75; kill -s ALRM $$ 2> /dev/null) &|
  psvar[1]=$(uptime)
  [[ -z $WIDGET ]] || zle reset-prompt
}
precmd_functions+=(TRAPALRM)
```

Another approach could be to have a loop sending the uptime every 750ms as a coproc, using `zle -F` to handle the output of that `coproc`:

```
zmodload zsh/system
zmodload zsh/zselect
UPTIME_TMOUT=
coproc {
  while true; do
    zselect -r 0 ${UPTIME_TMOUT:+-t} $UPTIME_TMOUT
    case $? in
      (0) IFS= read UPTIME_TMOUT || exit
          [[ -n $UPTIME_TMOUT ]] || continue;;
      (1) ;;
      (*) exit 1;;
    esac
    uptime
  done
}
sysopen -wu UPTIME_TO   -o cloexec /dev/fd/3 3>&p
sysopen -ru UPTIME_FROM -o cloexec /dev/fd/3 3<&p

handle_uptime_event() {
  if ! IFS= read -ru $UPTIME_FROM 'psvar[1]'; then
    zle -F $UPTIME_FROM
    exec {UPTIME_FROM}<&- {UPTIME_TO}>&-
    unset UPTIME_TO UPTIME_FROM
  fi
  zle reset-prompt
}

start_uptime_loop() {
  (($+UPTIME_TO)) && print -u $UPTIME_TO 75
}
stop_uptime_loop() {
  (($+UPTIME_TO)) && print -u $UPTIME_TO
}
zle -F $UPTIME_FROM handle_uptime_event
precmd_functions+=(start_uptime_loop)
preexec_functions+=(stop_uptime_loop)

RPS1=%1v
```